# Do I need to implement full text search in this case? alternatives?

Tags: sql, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, full-text-search

I have two columns in a table first_name and last_name(PostgreSQL).

In front end, I have an input to allow users to search for people. It is an auto-complete field that calls a web service for searching people by first and/or last names.

Currently, I have made a query (using my query builder):

```
        $searches = preg_split('/\s+/', $search);

        if (!empty($search)) {
            $orX = $query->expr()->orX();
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($searches as $value) {
                $orX->add($query->expr()->eq('c.firstName', ':name'.$i));
                $orX->add($query->expr()->eq('c.lastName', ':name'.$i));
                $query->setParameter('name'.$i, $value);
                $i++;
            }
            $query->andWhere($orX);
        }
```

But this query is not as precise as it is required, it uses OR for every word so if I am looking for "Rasmus Lerdorf" it also gives me "Rasmus Adams" and "Adel Lerdorf". It works only if I enter a single word ("Rasmus" for example), in this case it gives me all people with "Rasmus" as first_name or last_name.

I read about MATCH AGAINST but I am using PostgreSQL. I also heard about Full text search feature in PostgreSQL as the equivalent of MATCH AGAINST, but I am wondering if implementing a full text search would be an overkill for such an objective (especially that the maximum number of words in both columns wouldn't exceed 4).

I ask you please your advices, your usual help is always appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need fulltext search.

Just add the different search terms with AND instead of OR:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($searches as $value) {
    $orX = $query->expr()->orX();
    $orX->add($query->expr()->eq('c.firstName', ':name'.$i));
    $orX->add($query->expr()->eq('c.lastName', ':name'.$i));
    $query->setParameter('name'.$i, $value);
    $i++;
    $query->andWhere($orX);
}
```

I would also suggest using LIKE instead of an equality comparison (add '%' to the start and end of the users search term), and probably also make everything case insensitive by adding `$query->expr()->lower()` appropriately.